# How to connect xbox 360 controller to PC with only bluetooth

Tags: xbox360

I wanna try the xbox 360 controller but I don't have a cable or a receiver for it, I only have bluetooth.

Can you please tell me how to connect it to my PC (Windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't... Xbox 360 controllers do not support Bluetooth, they use a proprietary RF interface which requires a special USB dongle.

There are specific, newer **Xbox ONE** wireless controllers that [do support Bluetooth to PC](http://www.pcgamer.com/revised-xbox-one-controller-taps-bluetooth-to-work-with-pcs/), but you need to make sure to get the one with Bluetooth support as all Xbox One controllers do not support it.

Multiple references:

[Gamespot](https://www.gamespot.com/forums/pc-mac-linux-society-1000004/xbox-360-wireless-controller-and-pc-26375118/)
[Tom's Hardware Forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2080705/connect-xbox-controller-bluetooth.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. The XBox 360 controller does not use Bluetooth. You may be confusing it with the Playstation 3/4 controllers.

You need the receiver. Please note that the Play & Charge Kit does not contain a receiver.